# Sed find replace combination with less sign and slash and more sign

Tags: sed

I have a stumbling block with sed replace (Linux shell)

I need to replace

```
</test>
```

to

```
</test1>
```

tried

```
sed -i 's/<\/test>/</test1>/g'
```

and similar variants -but still no luck...so thanks for any hint to try

Comment: You missed `\/` in the replacement half.

Comment: Thanks for a hint ! Now I've got it working

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo '</test>' | sed 's|</test>|</test1>|'
```

Comment: This would be better with an explanation (even a succinct explanation) of what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

For what you tried, you need to escape the slash in the replacement string:

```
sed -i 's/<\/test>/<\/test1>/g'
```

Or change the regex boundary marker character:

```
sed -i 's%</test>%</test1>%g'
```